# Collect a word between two spaces in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to implement stuff similar to spell check, but I need to get the word that is limited by a space. EX: "HI HOW R U", I need to collect `HI`, `HOW` and so on as they type. i.e. After user hits `HI` and <kbd>space</kbd> I need to collect `HI` and do a spell check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check the documentation for NSString Here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a)  You want the message `componentsSepeparatedByString:`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know objective-C, but I'm fairly sure it'll have a Regexp library - although it'd be straightforward to code it without one.

```
Regexp: \b([^\s])*\b

\b = word boundary (whitespace, comma, dot, exclamation-mark, etc.)
\s = whitespace character
[...] = character set
[^...] = negated character set (any character(s) EXCEPT ...)
() = grouping construct
* = zero or more times
```

So the suggested expression would start matching at any word boundary, then match every subsequent character that is not a whitespace character, then match a word boundary.

Your stated case is so simple you may just want to look for spaces (one char at a time) and get the substring, but RegExp is very widely used across a range of languages and platforms, and so it's fairly easy to find an expression when you need to - and one often does for common stuff like checking if zip codes, phone numbers, email addresses and so on are syntactically correct. So it's worth learning in any case. :)

Comment: And btw, an *excellent* site for learning RegExp: [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)